# Using google social login vs google OIDC in GCP identity platform

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I'm trying to add authentication to a service running on GCP using Google Identity Platform. In the list of providers I can see *Google* as *social login* option and also *OIDC provider option* which in I can use `Google OIDC service`.

[image]

I wonder what's the difference between these two and why should I prefer using one over another?

I know OIDC uses OAuth2, but I'm not sure if this is also the case for using google social login.